# Prevent hover from changing link's height

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Using Angular, Angular Material, and Angular Flex-Layout, I have created a group of links that are styled like cards or tiles. When the links are not being hovered, an icon and title for the link are shown. When hovered, the icon and title no longer display and are replaced with informational text.

For items with a lot of informational text, this change of state is resulting in a height increase for the items.

I am able to fix this by hard-coding a `min-height` with pixels. However, if I try to use percent, like 110%, there is no change on the size of the links. The same is true for the div surrounding the links named `.container` .

Here is an excerpt:

```
<div class="container" fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="10px">

  <a mat-flat-button color="primary" fxFlex href="https://example.com/footprints">
    <div class="hoverOff"><fa-icon [icon]="faToolbox"></fa-icon>Broken</div>
    <div class="hoverOn">Is your request causing an impact to a business-critical function, which is impacting daily production?</div>
  </a>

  <a mat-flat-button color="primary" fxFlex href="https://example.com/divisions/dev/Lists/Requests/NewForm.aspx?isProject=Yes">
    <div class="hoverOff"><fa-icon [icon]="faPuzzlePiece"></fa-icon>Project</div>
    <div class="hoverOn">Is your request a new product or service?<br>
      Requires and RFI or RFP?<br>
      Requires more than 500 or more internal resource hours<br>
      Necessitates a cost greater then $100,000?<br>
      New banking center or remodel?<br>
      New Partnership, divestiture or branch closure?
    </div>
  </a>

</div>

<style>
.mat-flat-button {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
}

a {
    color: white !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

fa-icon {
    display: block;
    font-size: 75px;
}

.mat-primary {
    background-color: #00539B !important;
}

a .hoverOn {
    display: none;
}

a:hover .hoverOn {
    display: block;
}

a:hover .hoverOff {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

[I have created an example of this on StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dzel2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

How can I resolve this height-change without hard-coding for pixels?

Comment: @Marshal Not cut off. I want to be able to set the link height in a better way than using pixels. Doesn't seem like a very safe way to solve the size change on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to your CSS will prevent the height change on scroll, while using `45%` of the viewport height `vh`

```
.container{
  height:45vh
}
```

Also using the following will extend the container 10% beyond the `vh` for a total of 110%

```
.container{
  height:110vh
}
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1exhe?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking to adjust css of links, you could add something like this to the `a`  css:

```
 max-height:60vh; (or use percentage instead of vh, but set a max-height)   
 overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x:hidden;
```

Hope this helps.

[Example (I set your icon size to 35pt in this)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukdtra)

Comment: I put a space after the forward slash in the "Operational/ "  icon to wrap the text onto the next line.